# creating installer package in linux

Tags: python, linux

I have created a folder in which I kept all my python files. I have added `__init__.py` to that folder to create it as package. The main file is test.py in which I give input.

for example :

```
<filename>.py 10 20
```

Now, I have a package. I want to create installer from that package so that, other persons will download that package and install it as normal installation occurs in linux.

so that, after installation by typing test linux user should able to use my application.

example :

```
<filename> 10 20
```

How can I proceed to create such installer in linux for my package?

Comment: for which linux flavour you need to create a installer?

Comment: `test` is a system binary, you don't want your tool to use the same name.

Comment: @RahulRDhobi : ubuntu. how can I create for all linux flavours?

Comment: @tripleee : I just gave an example. for example when we download and install emacs, just by typing emacs we can use it. like wise my main file is test.py. I need user should access direct name "test"

Comment: I don't think we are communicating properly.  You need to call it something else.  Not `test` and not `emacs` either because those are already taken.

Comment: How is @icedtrees' answer not suitable for you?

Answer (score 2):

1. `init.py` <strike>should be `__init__.py` to be the initialisation script for a package.</strike> is caused by markdown (thanks) and is annoying.
2. A good way to create an installer (distutils) for a package is to create a setup.py file. A guide to writing this can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html). Once you write this script and include it in your package, the user will be able to install it by running "[sudo] python setup.py [options]"